# How do I float two elements of different widths to the left of one large block of text?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a blog article that contains three elements: 1) the post thumbnail, 2) a social media box, and 3) the article text. I want the text to float to the left of the thumbnail (easy enough) and I also want the text to float to the left of the social media box with the social media box displaying underneath the thumbnail. Another way of saying it is, I want the thumbnail to be above the social media box, but have the article text float to the left of them both. The problem is, the thumbnail is wider than the social media box, and there is a large gap to the right of the social media box to make up for the width of the thumbnail. How can I get the text to float to the left of both elements and fit snug up against both elements?

My code is available [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uvcac/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text to wrap each sidebar item individually by floating them separately, rather than wrapping all the items in a floated div:

```
.article-image, .sharebox-outer {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uvcac/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Give the  a specific width so that it fills up the entire containing div, pushing the floated social media box down.

```
h2.gentesque { float:left; width: 500px; }
.article-image { float:left; width: /* whatever width */ }
```

Comment: couldn't get this one to work. i think clear:left; is what i was missing. i may have just interpreted your answer incorrectly. thank you for the response.

Comment: Ben Blank's answer is much cleaner anyway. :)